# No destination directory found using robocopy in batch

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, robocopy

I am using robocopy to copy all files and folders from one directory to another.
The directory will be copied to a new time-stamped folder every time the script is executed.

However I am getting the follwoing error:

> No destination directory Specfied

Here is the code:

```
echo off


set newDirectory = C:\Users\cmooney\Desktop

set DirName=%date:~-4,4%.%date:~-7,2%.%date:~0,2%.%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%
MD \%newDirectory%

set source = C:\Users\cmooney\Desktop\FolderA



rem /e copy all subdirs /z try again if fails /NMir copy only new files 

robocopy %source% %DirName% /e /z /Mir


rem leave cmd line open
pause



REM If there are no changes, robocopy will not copy anything. If you have tried 

REM and it worked, .... if no changes, no file copy.
```

Any input appreciated

Comment: `MD %newDirectory%\%Dirname%`

Comment: `%newDirectory%` and `%source%` are not defined because there are spaces in the `SET` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the spaces in your `SET` commands. For example:

```
set source = C:\Users\cmooney\Desktop\FolderA
```

Creates a variabled named `%source %` (note the space on the end) with the value `C:\Users\cmooney\Desktop\FolderA` (note the space at the beginning).

So when you try to use `%source%`, it actually does not exist. This is the same with `%newDirectory%` as well.

Instead, set your variables like so:

```
set "newDirectory=C:\Users\cmooney\Desktop"
set "source=C:\Users\cmooney\Desktop\FolderA"
```

This will ensure any leading/trailing spaces are not included.